# If I have inputs in shape (32,256,256,3) and I want to create a custom loss function replicating the following equation in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Create custom Loss function in keras for y_pred and y_loss of shape (32,256,256,3) where 32 is the batch_size and 3 is the number of channels of the image of dimention 256x256 and the loss equation:

[image: equation]

It is given in this paper, the loss function for Surface Normals: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.4734.pdf

```
def normal_loss_1 (y_true, y_pred):    
    y_true_flat = K.flatten(y_true)
    y_pred_flat = K.flatten(y_pred)
    #d = y_pred_flat * y_true_flat
    d = np.dot(y_pred_flat,y_true_flat)
    y_sum = K.sum(d)
    n_pixels = 256 * 256
    normal_output = y_sum/n_pixels
    normal_output = tf.reduce_mean(normal_output)
    return -normal_output
```

I do not get any error with this but the result is not as expected. Is there any other and better way to write the code? Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using numpy to get dot product of tensors. Here `y_true_flat` and `y_pred_flat` are tensors. You should either use `tensorflow.tensordot` method or `tensorflow.keras.backend.dot` method to get product of two tensors. Since these tensors are vectors, `tensorflow.matmul` could also work.

```py
def normal_loss_1 (y_true, y_pred):    
    dim = tf.reduce_prod(tf.shape(y_true)[1:])
    y_true_flatten = tf.reshape(y_true, [-1, dim])
    y_pred_flatten = tf.reshape(y_pred, [-1, dim])
    d = tf.tensordot(y_pred_flatten,y_true_flatten, 1)
    y_sum = tf.reduce_sum(d, 1)
    n_pixels = 256 * 256
    normal_output = y_sum/n_pixels
    normal_output = tf.reduce_mean(normal_output)
    return -normal_output
```

#### Edit

`K.flatten` will convert the tensors(`y_true` and `y_pred`) into vectors and the batch dimension will disappear. This means you cannot average the loss over the batch.

Comment: Thank you for the help but I get the following error in line : y_sum = tf.reduce_sum(d, 1)
ValueError: Invalid reduction dimension 1 for input with 0 dimensions. for 'loss/activation_loss/Sum' (op: 'Sum') with input shapes: [], [] and with computed input tensors: input[1] = <1>.

Comment: You don't have to flatten `y_true` and `y_pred`. I've removed the lines.

Comment: I am sorry but that didn't solve the issue either. I am getting the following error:

Comment: File "our_train_normal.py", line 286, in <module>
    validation_data=(X_test,y_test),
  File "/home/ivlab/anaconda2/envs/tuto/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 880, in fit
    validation_steps=validation_steps)

Comment: File "/home/ivlab/anaconda2/envs/tuto/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_arrays.py", line 329, in model_iteration
    batch_outs = f(ins_batch)

Comment: File "/home/ivlab/anaconda2/envs/tuto/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py", line 3076, in __call__
    run_metadata=self.run_metadata)
  File "/home/ivlab/anaconda2/envs/tuto/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1439, in __call__
    run_metadata_ptr)

Comment: File "/home/ivlab/anaconda2/envs/tuto/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 528, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [2097152,3], In[1]: [32,196608]
  [[{{node loss/activation_loss/Tensordot/MatMul}}]]
  [[{{node loss/mul}}]]

Comment: I was wondering if tf.tensordot(y_pred,y_true,1) does not work for 4D tensors of shape (32,256,256,3)

Comment: Thank you, Sir. I appreciate your help but the code still gives me an error. However, I used another learning rate and that helped me get a good prediction.